# Autocomplete text input in reference to the value of another text input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have two fields, one of which has the [jQuery autoComplete plugin](http://www.mix26.com/demo/ajax-autocomplete/test.php).

```
<input type='text' name='primary_diagnosis' id='icd1-diagnosis'/>
<input type='text' name='ICD_No1' id='icd1-num' />

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#icd1-diagnosis").autocomplete("autocomplete-icd.php", 
    {
        selectFirst: true
    });
});
```

Is there a way to automatically fill up the second text input once a value has been selected for the first? For example, selecting "Dengue fever [classical dengue]" for the first text input, then query the database for certain value to yeild "A90" as the value for the second text input.

Here's autocomplete-icd.php

```
<?php
    include('config.php');
    $q=$_GET['q'];
    $my_data=$q;

    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT col9 FROM tb_data_icd WHERE col9 LIKE '%$my_data%' ORDER BY col9",$con);
    if($sql)
    {
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {
            $col9=$row['col9'];
            echo "$col9"."\n";
        }
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the change event to fire off some javascript to update the second input's value. Something like this:

```
$("#icd1-diagnosis").change(function(){
    //retrieve your value
    var val = 'sample';
    $('#icd1-num').val(val);
});
```